# Scraping a website which has a table but the next button on the table doesn't change the url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I wanted to scrape this link and get the whole table of players :- https://www.nba.com/stats/leaders/?StatCategory=FG3M&PerMode=Totals&Season=2015-16&SeasonType=Regular%20Season

Here, if you click on the next button in the table, the contents of the table changes but the url on the top doesn't change. But the button doesn't have a button tag. It looks like this:-

```
<a class="stats-table-pagination__next" href="" alt="Next Page" ng-click="nav(1)">       
    <i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

I tried using beautiful soup and selenium to scrape this website but I can't figure out how to navigate to other pages of the table so that I can scrape them too. Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use use google chrome in developer mode and find that json file containing all the data from image that you can see
2. Then go to Network tab and refresh link and go to xhr tab you will find lots of link from that one link contains players information
3. after getting that exact data click on that link copy address and use `requests` module get json data and extract the information

> ```
> import requests
> res=requests.get("https://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?LeagueID=00&PerMode=Totals&Scope=S&Season=2015-16&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StatCategory=FG3M")
> data=res.json()
> for i in range(len(data['resultSet']['rowSet'])):
>     print(data['resultSet']['rowSet'][i][2])
> ```

Output:

```
Stephen Curry
Klay Thompson
James Harden
Damian Lillard
..
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: This really helped, thanks. I am new to web scraping and I wanted to try this nba website, but your soution is the most efficient. I just want to ask whether this method where you went to the network tab and found the json file , and used that to extract the data.....can this method be used on most of the websites as well, and how did you learn about using it this way?

Comment: Yes we can use this method if data is dynamic and data is present by API so we can use that but it is not always there in many website so for that we have to change approach!